# SwiftUI List may crash when created with animation and .contextMenu

Tags: swiftui

I’m making a SwiftUI app for macOS.

When a button is tapped in the app header, a custom sidebar appears from the right side. The button switches a Boolean `withAnimation`, and the custom sidebar has the `.transition(.move(edge: .trailing))` modifier.

The sidebar contains some content and a List.

Sometimes, opening the sidebar causes crash: “Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x187e7cbd0)”

The console prints the following, which I did not find particularly helpful:
“The window has been marked as needing another Update Constraints in Window pass, but it has already had more Update Constraints in Window passes than there are views in the window.”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of testing, I found out this is caused by having `.contextMenu` over each row in the List.

Removing `.contextMenu` prevents the crash.

I’m putting this out there because it’s annoying, it might help someone else, and I currently don’t have the time to submit a full bug report to Apple for this extremely niche issue.

```
List($someData, editActions: [.delete, .move]) { $item in
    Text(item.wrappedName)
      .contextMenu { // <- the culprit
        Button(role: .destructive, action: {
          deleteItem
        }) {
          Text("Delete")
        }
     }
  }
  .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
```